# Why is Docker looking for a non-existent tag when using ${TAG:-latest} in .yml file?

Tags: docker

I’ve been working with a docker deployment and I’m seeing an irksome behavior: The full project is here (I'm using the v1.0.0-CODI tag): https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/anonlink-entity-service

Sometimes (often) I get the following error:

running:
docker-compose -p anonlink -f tools/docker-compose.yml up --remove-orphans

I get:
Pulling db_init (data61/anonlink-app:v1.15.0-22-gba57975)...
ERROR: manifest for data61/anonlink-app:v1.15.0-22-gba57975 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

anonlink-app is specified in the .yml file as:
data61/anonlink-app:${TAG:-latest}

How is it that docker looking for a non-existent tag?

The full .yml file is shown below.

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11.13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rX%QpV7Xgyrz
    volumes:
      - psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    #ports:
    #- 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -q -h db -p 5432 -U postgres
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-02-14T04-01-33Z
    command: server /export
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - minio:/export
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0

  # The flask application server
  backend:
    image: data61/anonlink-app:${TAG:-latest}
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_DB_MIN_CONNECTIONS=1
      - FLASK_DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS=10
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db_init
      - redis
      - minio
      - objectstore_init

  # The application server can also setup the database
  db_init:
    image: 
      data61/anonlink-app:${TAG:-latest}
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEBUG=true
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=rX%QpV7Xgyrz
      - FLASK_APP=entityservice
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "dockerize -wait tcp://db:5432 alembic upgrade head"
    depends_on:
      - db

  # Set up the object store to have another more restricted user
  objectstore_init:
    image: minio/mc:RELEASE.2021-02-14T04-28-06Z
    environment:
      - OBJECT_STORE_SECURE=false
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: |
      /bin/sh /opt/init-object-store.sh
    volumes:
      - ./init-object-store.sh:/opt/init-object-store.sh:ro
    depends_on:
      - minio

  # A celery worker
  worker:
    image: data61/anonlink-app:${TAG:-latest}
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    command: celery -A entityservice.async_worker worker --loglevel=info -O fair -Q celery,compute,highmemory
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - CELERY_ACKS_LATE=true
      - REDIS_USE_SENTINEL=false
      - CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=2048
      #- CHUNK_SIZE_AIM=300_000_000
      - CELERY_DB_MIN_CONNECTIONS=1
      - CELERY_DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS=3


  nginx:
    image: data61/anonlink-nginx:${TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - 8851:8851
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      TARGET_SERVICE: backend
      PUBLIC_PORT: 8851


  # A celery monitor. Useful for debugging.
#  celery_monitor:
#    image: data61/anonlink-app:${TAG:-latest}
#    depends_on:
#      - redis
#      - worker
#    command: celery flower -A entityservice.async_worker
#    ports:
#      - 8888:8888


# Jaeger UI is available at http://localhost:16686
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    environment:
      COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT: 9411
#    ports:
#      - 5775:5775/udp
#      - 6831:6831/udp
#      - 6832:6832/udp
#      - 5778:5778
#      - 16686:16686
#      - 14268:14268
#      - 9411:9411

volumes:
  psql:
  minio:
```

This values.yaml file also exists in the project (note is uses v1.15.1, not v1.15.0-22-gba57975)

```
rbac:
  ## TODO still needs work to fully lock down scope etc
  ## See issue #88
  create: false

anonlink:

  ## Set arbitrary environment variables for the API and Workers.
  config: {
            ## e.g.: to control which task is added to which celery worker queue.
            ## CELERY_ROUTES: "{
            ## 'entityservice.tasks.comparing.create_comparison_jobs': { 'queue': 'highmemory' }, ...
            ## }"
  }

  objectstore:
    ## Settings for the Object Store that Anonlink Entity Service uses internally

    ## Connect to the object store using https
    secure: false

    ## Settings for uploads via Object Store

    ## Toggle the feature providing client's with restricted upload access to the object store.
    ## By default we don't expose the Minio object store, which is required for clients to upload
    ## via the object store. See section `minio.ingress` to create an ingress for minio.
    uploadEnabled: true

    ## Server used as the external object store URL - provided to clients so should be externally
    ## accessible. If not provided, the minio.ingress is used (if enabled).
    #uploadServer: "s3.amazonaws.com"

    ## Tell clients to make secure connections to the upload object store.
    uploadSecure: true

    ## Object store credentials used to grant temporary upload access to clients
    ## Will be created with an "upload only" policy for a upload bucket if using the default
    ## MINIO provisioning.
    uploadAccessKey: "EXAMPLE_UPLOAD_KEY"
    uploadSecretKey: "EXAMPLE_UPLOAD_SECRET"

    ## The bucket for client uploads.
    uploadBucket:
      name: "uploads"

    ## Settings for downloads via Object Store

    ## Toggle the feature providing client's with restricted download access to the object store.
    ## By default we don't expose the Minio object store, which is required for clients to download
    ## via the object store.
    downloadEnabled: true

    ## Tell clients to make secure connections to the download object store.
    downloadSecure: true

    ## Server used as the external object store URL for downloads - provided to clients so
    ## should be externally accessible. If not provided, the minio.ingress is used (if enabled).
    #downloadServer: "s3.amazonaws.com"

    ## Object store credentials used to grant temporary download access to clients
    ## Will be created with an "get only" policy if using the default MINIO provisioning.
    downloadAccessKey: "EXAMPLE_DOWNLOAD_KEY"
    downloadSecretKey: "EXAMPLE_DOWNLOAD_SECRET"


api:

  ## Deployment component name
  name: api
  ## Defines the serviceAccountName to use when `rbac.create=false`
  serviceAccountName: default

  replicaCount: 1

  ## api Deployment Strategy type
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  #   type: Recreate

  ## Annotations to be added to api pods
  ##
  podAnnotations: {}
    # iam.amazonaws.com/role: linkage

  ## Annotations added to the api Deployment
  deploymentAnnotations: # {}
    # This annotation enables jaeger injection for open tracing
    "sidecar.jaegertracing.io/inject": "true"

  ## Settings for the nginx proxy
  www:

    image:
      repository: data61/anonlink-nginx
      tag: "v1.4.9"
      # pullPolicy: Always
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

    ## Nginx proxy server resource requests and limits
    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 256Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 256Mi

  app:
    image:
      repository: data61/anonlink-app
      tag: "v1.15.1"
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent


    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 8Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi

  dbinit:
    enabled: "true"

    ## Database init runs migrations after install and upgrade
    image:
      repository: data61/anonlink-app
      tag: "v1.15.1"

    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi

    ## Annotations added to the database init job's pod.
    # podAnnotations: {}
    #   sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"

  ## A job that creates an upload only object store user.
  objectstoreinit:
    enabled: true

    image:
      repository: minio/mc
      tag: RELEASE.2020-01-13T22-49-03Z

    ## Annotations added to the object store init job's pod.
    # podAnnotations: {}
    #   sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"


  ingress:
    ## By default, we do not want the service to be accessible outside of the cluster.
    enabled: false

    ## Ingress annotations
    annotations: {}
      ## Suggested annotations
      ## To handle large uploads we increase the proxy buffer size
      #ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 4096m

      ## Redirect to ssl
      #ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"

      ## Deprecated but common
      ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation
      # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ""

    path: /
    pathType: Prefix

    ## Entity Service API Ingress hostnames
    ## Must be provided if Ingress is enabled
    hosts: []
     ## E.g:
     #- beta.anonlink.data61.xyz

    ## Ingress TLS configuration
    ## This example setup is for nginx-ingress. We use certificate manager.
    ## to create the TLS secret in the namespace with the name
    ## below.
    tls:  []

    ## secretName is the kubernetes secret which will contain the TLS secret and certificates
    ## for the provided host url. It is automatically generated from the deployed cert-manager.
    #- secretName: beta-anonlink-data61-tls
    #  hosts:
    #  - beta.anonlink.data61.xyz

  service:
    annotations: []
    labels:
      tier: frontend
    clusterIp: ""

    ## Expose the service to be accessed from outside the cluster (LoadBalancer service).
    ## or access it from within the cluster (ClusterIP service).
    ## Set the service type and the port to serve it.
    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/
    ## Most likely ingress is enabled so this should be ClusterIP,
    ## Otherwise "LoadBalancer".
    type: ClusterIP
    servicePort: 80

    ## If using a load balancer on AWS you can optionally lock down access
    ## to a given IP range. Provide a list of IPs that are allowed via a
    ## security group.
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: []

workers:
  name: "matcher"

  image:
    repository: "data61/anonlink-app"
    tag: "v1.15.1"
    pullPolicy: Always

  ## The initial number of workers for this deployment
  ## Note the workers.highmemory.replicaCount are in addition
  replicaCount: 1

  ## Enable a horizontal pod autoscaler
  ## Note: The cluster must have metrics-server installed.
  ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/
  autoscaler:
    enabled: false
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 20

  podAnnotations: {}

  deploymentAnnotations: # {}
    # This annotation enables jaeger injection for open tracing
    "sidecar.jaegertracing.io/inject": "true"

  #strategy: ""

  ## Additional Entity Service Worker container arguments
  ##
  extraArgs: {}

  ## Worker configuration
  ## These settings populate the deployment's configmap.

  ## Desired task size in "number of comparisons"
  ## Note there is some overhead creating a task and a single dedicated cpu core can do between 50M and 100M
  ## comparisons per second, so much lower that 100M isn't generally worth splitting across celery workers.
  CHUNK_SIZE_AIM: "300_000_000"

  ## More than this many entities and we skip caching in redis
  MAX_CACHE_SIZE: "1_000_000"

  ## How many seconds do we keep cache ephemeral data such as run progress
  ## Default is 30 days:
  CACHE_EXPIRY_SECONDS: "2592000"

  ## Specific configuration for celery
  ## Note that these configurations are the same for a "normal" worker, and a "highmemory" one,
  ## except for the requested resources and replicaCount which can differ.
  celery:
    ## Number of fork worker celery node will have. It is recommended to use the same concurrency
    ## as workers.resources.limits.cpu
    CONCURRENCY: "2"
    ## How many messages to prefetch at a time multiplied by the number of concurrent processes. Set to 1 because
    ## our tasks are usually quite "long".
    PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER: "1"
    ## Maximum number of tasks a pool worker process can execute before it’s replaced with a new one
    MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD: "2048"
    ## Late ack means the task messages will be acknowledged after the task has been executed, not just before.
    ACKS_LATE: "true"

  ## Currently, enable only the monitoring of celery.
  monitor:
    enabled: false

  ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 500Mi
      cpu: 500m
    ## It is recommended to set limits. celery does not like to share resources.
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 2

  ## At least one "high memory" worker is also required.
  highmemory:
    replicaCount: 1
    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 2Gi
        cpu: 1
      ## It is recommended to set limits. celery does not like to share resources.
      limits:
        memory: 2Gi
        cpu: 2

postgresql:
  ## See available settings and defaults at:
  ## https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql
  nameOverride: "db"

  persistence:
    enabled: false
    size: 8Gi

  metrics:
    enabled: true
    #serviceMonitor:
      #enabled: true
      #namespace:

  ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  resources:
    #limits:
    #  memory: 8Gi
    requests:
      #memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 200m


global:

  postgresql:
    postgresqlDatabase: postgres
    postgresqlUsername: postgres
    postgresqlPassword: "examplePostgresPassword"


## In this section, we are not installing Redis. The main goal is to define configuration values for
## other services that need to access Redis.
redis:
  ## Note the `server` options are ignored if provisioning redis
  ## using this chart.

  ## External redis server url/ip
  server: ""

  ## Does the redis server support the sentinel protocol
  useSentinel: true
  sentinelName: "mymaster"

  ## Note if deploying redis-ha you MUST have the same password below!
  password: "exampleRedisPassword"


redis-ha:
  ## Settings for configuration of a provisioned redis ha cluster.
  ## https://github.com/DandyDeveloper/charts/tree/master/charts/redis-ha#configuration
  ## Provisioning is controlled in the `provision` section
  auth: true
  redisPassword: "exampleRedisPassword"
  #replicas: 3
  redis:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 512Mi
        cpu: 100m
      limits:
        memory: 10Gi
  sentinel:
    ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        memory: 256Mi
  persistentVolume:
    enabled: false
    size: 10Gi
  nameOverride: "memstore"

  # Enable transparent hugepages
  # https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha#host-kernel-settings
  sysctlImage:
    enabled: true
    mountHostSys: true
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -xc
      - |-
        sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=10000
        echo never > /host-sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
  # Enable prometheus exporter sidecar
  exporter:
    enabled: true

minio:
  ## Configure the object storage
  ## https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/minio/values.yaml

  ## Root access credentials for the object store
  ## Note no defaults are provided to help prevent data breaches where
  ## the object store is exposed to the internet
  #accessKey: "exampleMinioAccessKey"
  #secretKey: "exampleMinioSecretKet"

  defaultBucket:
    enabled: true
    name: "anonlink"

  ## Settings for deploying standalone object store
  ## Can distribute the object store across multiple nodes.
  mode: "standalone"
  service.type: "ClusterIP"
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    size: 50Gi
    storageClass: "default"

  metrics:
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: false
      #additionalLabels: {}
      #namespace: nil

  # If you'd like to expose the MinIO object store
  ingress:
    enabled: false
    #labels: {}
    #annotations: {}
    #hosts: []
    #tls: []

  nameOverride: "minio"
  
  ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 100m
    limits:
      memory: 5Gi


provision:
  # enable to deploy a standalone version of each service as part of the helm deployment
  minio: true
  postgresql: true
  redis: true


## Tracing config used by jaeger-client-python
## https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python/blob/master/jaeger_client/config.py
tracingConfig: |-
  logging: true
  metrics: true
  sampler:
    type: const
    param: 1

## Custom logging file used to override the default settings. Will be used by the workers and the api container.
## Example of logging configuration:
loggingCfg: |-
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: False
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: "%(message)s"
    file:
      format: "%(asctime)-15s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s"
  filters:
    stderr_filter:
      (): entityservice.logger_setup.StdErrFilter
    stdout_filter:
      (): entityservice.logger_setup.StdOutFilter

  handlers:
    stdout:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      filters: [stdout_filter]
      stream: ext://sys.stdout

    stderr:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: ERROR
      formatter: simple
      filters: [stderr_filter]
      stream: ext://sys.stderr

    info_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: INFO
      formatter: file
      filename: info.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: ERROR
      formatter: file
      filename: errors.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8

  loggers:
    entityservice:
      level: INFO

    entityservice.database.util:
      level: WARNING

    entityservice.cache:
      level: WARNING

    entityservice.utils:
      level: INFO

    celery:
      level: INFO

    jaeger_tracing:
      level: WARNING
      propagate: no

    werkzeug:
      level: WARNING
      propagate: no

  root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [stdout, stderr, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

This is also interesting...

According to the web site https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/develop/ the tag v1.15.0 seems to exists

[image]

[image]

The .env file looks like this:

```
SERVER=http://nginx:8851

DATABASE_PASSWORD=myPassword

# Object Store Configuration

# Provide root credentials to MINIO to set up more restricted service accounts
# MC_HOST_alias is equivalent to manually configuring a minio host
# mc config host add minio http://minio:9000 <MINIO_ACCESS_KEY> <MINIO_SECRET_KEY>
#- MC_HOST_minio=http://AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY@minio:9000
MINIO_SERVER=minio:9000
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
MINIO_SECRET_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
MINIO_SECURE=false

# Object store account which will have upload only object store access.
#UPLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SERVER=
UPLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_BUCKET=uploads
UPLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SECURE=false
UPLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_ACCESS_KEY=EXAMPLE_UPLOAD_ACCESS_KEY
UPLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SECRET_KEY=EXAMPLE_UPLOAD_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

# Object store account which will have "read only" object store access.
#DOWNLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SERVER=
DOWNLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_ACCESS_KEY=EXAMPLE_DOWNLOAD_ACCESS_KEY
DOWNLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SECRET_KEY=EXAMPLE_DOWNLOAD_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
DOWNLOAD_OBJECT_STORE_SECURE=false

# Logging, monitoring and metrics
LOG_CFG=entityservice/verbose_logging.yaml
JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger

SOLVER_MAX_CANDIDATE_PAIRS=500000000 
SIMILARITY_SCORES_MAX_CANDIDATE_PAIRS=999000000
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a `.env` file somewhere next to your `docker-compose.yml`? If so, I'd suggest to go and have a peek at it.

Comment: And the next thing would be to do `echo $TAG` in your command prompt

Comment: .env file has been added

Comment: It does look like the process set an env variable somewhere along the line.  Echo %TAG% give the string being used by the build.  If I run in a new cmd window, everything seems to work, but there is no mention of anonlink-app in the output from docker-compose -p anonlink -f tools/docker-compose.yml up --remove-orphans. I'm 100% certain I did not set the %TAG% env variable manually.